# UITableView fine in iOS 8 but collapsed in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8

I have been looking at this iOS application for a while, basically the tables are all fine in iOS8 however, when running in iOS7 they all have no height.

The original spec called for just iOS8 support but due to some customers only have iPhone 4s backward compatibility as been asked for. Below is a screenshot of what is happening. Any help would be great.

In **viewDidLoad**

```
self.myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140.0;
self.myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Also it has this function:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:   
                                          (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

[image: left iOS7, right iOS8]

In the storyboards the cells which are collapsing are just basic cells. With the following properties:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only iOS 8 and later versions supports `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: UITableViewAutomaticDimension is prior to iOS 8

Comment: You have to conditionally change the height of the table view cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change size conditionally

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue]>=8.0)
    {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
    else{
        //Calulate size of cell and return it from here. like as
        return 40;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok  thank you. 

For simple pages like this one, that will work great, but dynamic cell height pages I will have to do a lot of work within the else.

Comment: @KevinMann Yes, you have to count the text size per label and all the things. iOS 8 gives great functionality :)

Comment: I will I had to wait 5 minutes before I could. :)